# Should I use GitHub OAuth or a GitHub App?

Tags: node.js, github, oauth, command-line-interface

I'm building a nodejs command-line tool which takes the output from a client and pushes it to a GitHub repo and raise a PR.

The purpose behind it is that our users need to produce something that our team can process as code but our users are not coders, therefore they only need to complete a form and the code will be created for them. When they submit the form it will give them a preview of the code (on the off chance they know what they are doing but mostly to make them feel like coders) but in the background, it will push that code to a repo and raise a PR so we as developers get alerted to the new code. GitHub is being used for version-control and diffing abilities and is a specific request from the powers that be.

The users will not have GitHub accounts and really shouldn't even need to be aware that any GitHub stuff is happening so we don't want them to have to authenticate, instead we'd want the server itself to authenticate with GitHub using a token.

My question is, should it be an oAuth token or a GitHub app token? Apologies if it's a dumb question, not worked with Octokit before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should choose oAuth token :)

Comment: Thanks, I did a few experiment versions and that's the route I went with, in the end :)

Answer (score -1):

i am also facing same situation.

what i read about OAuth App is if you want to use third application and using github identity to sign in . In this case you use OAUTH app.

While Github APP, if you want to access the github organisation repo or github user specific stuff.

Please correct me.Also share your scenario for more understanding.

Comment: This is a suggestion not an answer.

Comment: Yes it is a suggestion as i did not have enough reputation to put under question suggestion  .

Comment: That doesn't mean you can add it as an answer. Please remove this.